# While someone's ears pops with pressure, can he/she hear other sound at the same time?

Tags: hearing, human-ear

I know that after or before someone's ears pops because of pressure changes, he/she can hear the sound such as laughter. But can these two things ("her ears popped with pressure" and "she can hear the laughter") happen at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course they can. What happens when your ears feel 'full' like on an aeroplane is that the air pressure in the middle ear is different from the air pressure outside. When you 'pop' your ears, you push open the Eustachian tubes that connect the middle ear to the throat and make the pressure equal. No matter what the air pressure, the air still conducts sounds. The difference is that your ear drum moves a bit less if the middle ear pressure and outside pressure is different, thus why sound is muffled before you pop your ears.

[image: Eustachian tubes]

Comment: the air still conducts sounds---yeah, that's the key, thank you ! can we hear a sound like a "pop" when we pop our ears?

Comment: Sort of! it's kind of similar to the noise you hear when you swallow saliva as well as a gentle 'popping' feeling and relief.

Comment: aha!I see. and if the pressure of inside and outside is highly imbalanced, then the sound of a "pop" will not be gentle, and will be like a really "pop", right?

Comment: @Lincoln I guess so?

Comment: maybe having an extreme experience like this will know it...but the one will be deaf, right?...

Comment: @Lincoln well usually if the pressure on either side is different your hearing is a bit muffled. If there is an extreme pressure difference (from a combination of Eustachian tube blockage, infection & air travel, or more commonly a momentary difference caused by a huge sound like an explosion) your eardrum will burst. This is called 'barotrauma'

Comment: @Lincoln no problem! I'm guessing you've never felt your ears pop?

Comment: yeah, being seen through by you...  (hope you understand what i am saying... pardon my my bad english...not a native speaker).